# Prestashop 1.5 - Import huge data(categories, products, customers, addresses) from another prestashop 1.4 installation,

Tags: php, mysql, migration, prestashop

i have prestashop 1.5 installed on server A, on server B there is prestashop 1.4 installed with thousands of products and database size is about 500mb. I want to import all those products, categories, customers and their addresses from 1.4 installation to 1.5 installation.  I have access to both servers. CSV export for products is taking like forever what should i do to import this all to 1.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you already have the simplest solution : CSV...

Exporting you database via PMA won't work since the data model of PrestaShop is not the same in 1.5...it should have been called 2.0 :-)

What you can try is upgrading your current install of PrestaShop 1.4 using the autoupgrade module provided by PrestaShop. Don't forget to keep backups since this module is not stable.

Hope it helps,

Br,

Comment: i have tried this module and it worked, but website is loading too slow and database size is about 3gb now!

Comment: wow. You should give your feedback on the PrestaShop forums. Maybe it will help them improving the software.

Answer (score 1):

Be carefull, new version of autoupgrade module is not working for upgrade between 1.4 and 1.5.
That was causing a lot of problems and bugs, so its better run a new PS 1.5 install.

Answer (score 0):

Try do it with phpMyAdmin. Export tables from database "A" and import them into the database "B". Use the SQL format for export. It is hard, but I've done before and it works.

> - Another way is you clone the database "A" into database "B". And proceed as a update process.

Comment: it's not possible to do such a thing from PrestaShop 1.4 to PrestaShop 1.5 since the data structure changed a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use Prestashop Store Manager software to export products from PS 1.4 and than you will be able to import them to PS 1.5.

You can use this software for a month for free without limits.

Answer (score 0):

All data migration to 1.5, 1.6 CSV import/export Module

This module can help you. Export/Import all favorite data from prestashop from 1.4 to 1.5/1.6 & 1.5 to 1.6

This module allows you to export any size all data(Categories, Products, Combinations, Customers, Addresses, Manufacturers, Suppliers) from PrestaShop 1.4.X to PrestaShop 1.5.X and 1.6.X.  Also from 1.5.X to 1.6.X without data lose.  Usage of this module doesn’t require any special technical skills, it is easy to use. It help you to save your time from routine work of manual data migration.

http://addons.prestashop.com/en/export-modules/8934-all-data-migration-to-15-16-csv-import-export.html

Comment: not is free! http://addons.prestashop.com/en/export-modules/8934-export-csv-data-for-15-import.html